# ASP.NET MVC unit testing

Tags: c#

I have created a program in Visual Studio 2017, and I just noticed now that I forgot to add unit testing when creating it, and I am too far gone to start over.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is there any reason "add unit tests" is not a sufficient answer?

Comment: yeah sure the is a need to add unit testing

Comment: Not sure, but I'm guessing the OP's problem is with the VS interface. He/she does know how to add unit tests to a project at the beginning, but not after it is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to right-click on the solution, and Add Project, then Unit Test Project. Unless you're not using MSTest, then add a new project and choose class library.